# Populating an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

Let us say I have an object Airport with members airportCode and airportCity like this:

```
function Airport(airportCode, airportCity) {
        this.airportCode = airportCode;
        this.airportCity = airportCity;
    };
```

How can I create an array of objects Airport to which I can add. In Java, this would work like this:

```
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    Airport a = new Airport();
    a.airportCode = st.nextToken();
    a.airportCity = st.nextToken();
    airports.add(a);
}
```

Comment: Create an array using `var airports = [];`. Then, in the loop, create an `Airport` instance, and add it to the array using the [`airports.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method.

Comment: What is `st` in your javascript code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A very short answer:

```
airports.push(new Airport("code","city"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
function Airport(airportCode, airportCity) {
        this.airportCode = airportCode;
        this.airportCity = airportCity;
};

var dataArray = [];

for(var i=0; i< 10; i++){
    dataArray[i] = new Airport("Code-" + i, "City" + i);
}
```

Comment: Or simply `dataArray.push(new Airport(...));` which is slightly faster. :-)

Comment: here's another http://jsperf.com/push-vs-index-2 To show that it's much easier to write as well.

Comment: I take back my previous comment since the results are not consistent across browsers/os.

Answer (score 4):

It's not really that different

```
var airports = [];
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    var a = new Airport();
    a.airportCode = st.nextToken();
    a.airportCity = st.nextToken();
    airports.push(a);
}
```